# WSO2 DSS Query Result Inconsistent

Tags: database, wso2, database-connection, wso2-data-services-server

We have a blocking issue trying to execute queries via WSO2 DSS.

After a day of usage, the query results are not being retrieved by DSS consistently. (The same query might return results in the next try)

Using a network monitoring tool, we could find the DB responds almost immediately, however DSS did not acknowledge this response.

The same code in Acceptance env did not have this problem.
This is what i get in my log : 

    `[2015-11-27 09:45:17,308]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-1366
    [2015-11-27 09:45:17,314]  WARN - TargetHandler http-outgoing-1267: Connection time out while in state: REQUEST_DONE
    [2015-11-27 09:45:17,315]  WARN - FaultHandler ERROR_CODE : 101507
    [2015-11-27 09:45:17,315]  WARN - FaultHandler ERROR_MESSAGE : Error in Sender
    [2015-11-27 09:45:17,315]  WARN - FaultHandler ERROR_DETAIL : Error in Sender
    [2015-11-27 09:45:17,316]  WARN - FaultHandler ERROR_EXCEPTION : null
    [2015-11-27 09:45:17,316]  WARN - FaultHandler FaultHandler : Endpoint     [Sample_First]
[2015-11-27 09:45:17,316]  WARN - FailoverEndpoint Endpoint [getMyOverviewServiceEndpoint] Detect a Failure in a child endpoint : Endpoint [Sample_First]`

Any pointers could be of great help!

Thanks,

Siby Mathew

**Update**

Could find that WSO2 initially connects to Google DNS in the production, gets timed out and then connect to proper DNS to resolve the Database server.

- Could this be the reason for the inconsistent behaviour ?
- Is there any default code in DSS to connect to Google DNS ?

Comment: do you get anything on logs?

Comment: post wso2 server log